# PHP mail function not working on new Exchange 2010 Server

Tags: smtp, php, exchange-server-2010

When trying to send mail (to email addresses within the domain) using PHP's mail() function on my new Exchange 2010 server I get the error:

> mail(): SMTP server response: 501 5.1.3 Invalid address

I tried creating a new receive connector with anonymous authentication but that doesn't seem to help, and honestly I have little to no experience with Exchange Server.

The address is valid, btw.

Comment: What's in Exchange's server-side logs? Error messages returned to client-side apps are by design vague to prevent any kind of internal configuration data from leaking for security reasons.

Comment: Figured it out, apparently the Exchange server just didn't like the way I was CCing in the header, using the example from the PHP mail() function page. Once I removed it the mail sent without a problem.

Comment: You post your comment as the answer then. It helped me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this on top:

```
ini_set("sendmail_from", "email@yourdomian.com");
```

It'll work